# Sonarqube thrashing when doing AST scan on old Apache Axis 1.2.1 generated code

Tags: sonarqube, axis

On some code that was generated by Apache Axis 1.2.1, sonarqube started to have issues scanning it. It gets stuck on the file and then seems to eat up memory and keep running GC until it eventually stops.

It will log errors like the following

```
    Java Main Files AST scan...
    11 source files to be analyzed
    9/11 files analyzed, current is /bamboo-path/TestProjectWAR/src/main/java/com/example/sonar/bug/Contact.java
    9/11 files analyzed, current is /bamboo-path/TestProjectWAR/src/main/java/com/example/sonar/bug/Contact.java    
    [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 13,241ms last 8 cycles average is 2,192ms
...
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project TestProject: GC overhead limit exceeded -> [Help 1]
```

I believe this started after we updated to java plugin 3.3, but I'm not 100% on that.

Here's a paired down version of the code

```
public class Contact implements java.io.Serializable {
private java.lang.String cccCntctSeqNo;
private java.lang.Object __equalsCalc = null;

@Override
public synchronized boolean equals(java.lang.Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Contact)) {
        return false;
    }
    Contact other = (Contact) obj;
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (__equalsCalc != null) {
        return (__equalsCalc == obj);
    }
    __equalsCalc = obj;
    boolean _equals;
    _equals = true
        && ((this.cccCntctSeqNo == null && other.getCccCntctSeqNo() == null) || (this.cccCntctSeqNo != null && this.cccCntctSeqNo
            .equals(other.getCccCntctSeqNo())))
    __equalsCalc = null;
    return _equals;
}

private boolean __hashCodeCalc = false;

@Override
public synchronized int hashCode() {
    if (__hashCodeCalc) {
        return 0;
    }
    __hashCodeCalc = true;
    int _hashCode = 1;
    if (getCccCntctSeqNo() != null) {
        _hashCode += getCccCntctSeqNo().hashCode();
    }
    __hashCodeCalc = false;
    return _hashCode;
}
```

}

Has anyone else come across this or found any work arounds?

Comment: Would you be able to narrow down on which rule this is happening ? Sounds like a check is doing nasty things in memory but there is no way to pinpoint that from the log. What you can do is remove half of the rules in quality profile to narrow down to the culprit rule.

Comment: One of the rules that I can toggle on / off to get the build to fail is 'Conditions should not unconditionally evaluate to "TRUE" or to "FALSE"'
squid:S2583

Comment: Sounds like you are hitting this issue : http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1063 Would you be able to try a dev version of the java plugin to confirm that the issue is fixed in 3.4 ?

Comment: Sure I can try it. Where / what are the instructions?

Comment: You can try using this snapshot version : https://sonarplugins.ci.cloudbees.com/job/sonar-java/lastStableBuild/org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java$sonar-java-plugin/artifact/org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java/sonar-java-plugin/3.4-SNAPSHOT/sonar-java-plugin-3.4-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: Yes, the 3.4 snapshot with the following details seems to work when I re-enable that rule.

Build-Time: 2015-07-02T04:02:29+0200
Implementation-Build: 94061fdbbfefe228d179fddcfb34c2b7f9ca214e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are hitting this known issue : http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1063

Release containing the fix is about to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where it used to hung on Journal Flushing and ultimately timeout at whatever the value i set in Windbags Java default timeout in sonarqube.

I resolved this by using the following options while running the sonar man command:-
MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx4096m -XX:+UseSerialGC"

This has fixed the issue for me.