# Sonarqube stuck an an infinate loop when looking at a java file

Tags: java, sonarqube

When upgrading the java plugin from 3.5 to 3.6, the build gets stuck on a file and never times out. The problem also exists in 3.7.

It looks similar to another problem I recently had, but it does not seem to ever actually timeout or crash. The build just never stops.
[Sonarqube thrashing when doing AST scan on old Apache Axis 1.2.1 generated code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30895150/2055199)

Is there an easy way to determine which rule might be causing the trouble with logging or to just add a timeout?

**Update:**
Here is some code to reproduce the issue

```
public class SonarIssue {

public SonarIssue() {
    super();
}

private List getOfficials(int quarterId, int categoryCode, boolean current) throws RuntimeException {

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    boolean newTransaction = false;
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    try {
        String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT " + "  o.client_ofcl_fst_nm, " + "  o.client_ofcl_lst_nm, "
            + "  o.client_ofcl_ttl_nm_e, " + "  o.client_ofcl_ttl_nm_f, " + "  o.client_ofcl_seq_no, "
            + "  o.client_ofcl_sctr_nm_e, " + "  o.client_ofcl_sctr_nm_f, " + "  o.client2_ofcl_ctgry_cd, "
            + "  o.client_ofcl_end_dt " + "FROM  client_ofcl_tbl o, " + "      client2_rptg_qtr_tbl q "
            + "WHERE q.client2_rptg_qtr_seq_no = ? " + "  AND o.client2_ofcl_ctgry_cd = ? "
            + "  AND ((o.client_ofcl_strt_dt <= " + "        q.client2_rptg_qtr_end_dt) "
            + "   OR   o.client_ofcl_strt_dt IS NULL)" + "  AND ((o.client2_ofcl_dsclsr_lst_dt >= "
            + "        q.client2_rptg_qtr_strt_dt) " + "   OR   o.client2_ofcl_dsclsr_lst_dt IS NULL)";

        if (current) {
            sql = sql + " AND ((o.client_ofcl_end_dt >= " + "      q.client2_rptg_qtr_strt_dt) "
                + "  OR  o.client_ofcl_end_dt IS NULL)";
        } else {
            sql = sql + " AND o.client_ofcl_end_dt < " + "     q.client2_rptg_qtr_strt_dt ";
        }

        sql = sql + " ORDER BY nlssort(o.client_ofcl_lst_nm, " + "          'NLS_SORT = FRENCH'), "
            + "          nlssort(o.client_ofcl_fst_nm, " + "          'NLS_SORT = FRENCH') ";

        connection = getConnection();

        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, quarterId);
        preparedStatement.setInt(2, categoryCode);

        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            SonarqubeOfficial official = new SonarqubeOfficial();
            official.setFirstName(resultSet.getString(1));
            official.setLastName(resultSet.getString(2));
            official.setTitleEn(resultSet.getString(3));
            official.setTitleFr(resultSet.getString(4));
            official.setOfficialId(resultSet.getInt(5));
            official.setSectorEn(resultSet.getString(6));
            official.setSectorFr(resultSet.getString(7));
            official.setCategoryCd(resultSet.getInt(8));

            // Check if each official has an expense
            if (hasExpensesForQuarter(Integer.toString(official.getOfficialId()), quarterId)) {
                official.setHasExpenses(true);
            } else {
                official.setHasExpenses(false);
            }

            list.add(official);
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        RuntimeException exception = new RuntimeException("error.database.default", sqle);
        throw exception;
    } finally {
        if (newTransaction) {
            // TODO stop a transaction
        } else {
            closeResources(new Object[]{resultSet, preparedStatement});
        }
    }

    return list;
}

public boolean hasExpensesForQuarter(String officialId, int quarterId) throws RuntimeException {
    return true;
}

// below are methods that are from libraries. Since these are default return values, the code would never actually
// work.

public Connection getConnection() {
    return null;
}

public static void closeResources(Object[] connResources) {

    for (Object connResource : connResources) {
        if (connResource != null) {
            try {
                if (connResource instanceof java.sql.Connection) {
                    ((Connection) connResource).close();
                } else if (connResource instanceof java.sql.ResultSet) {
                    ((ResultSet) connResource).close();
                } else if (connResource instanceof java.sql.Statement) {
                    ((Statement) connResource).close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}

public class SonarqubeOfficial implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5888521931094795053L;

private int officialId;

private int categoryCd;

private String lastName;

private String firstName;

private String titleEn;

private String titleFr;

private String sectorEn;

private String sectorFr;

private boolean hasExpenses;

private boolean isReporting;

private String lastReportingDate;

private String startDate;

private String endDate;

private String lastModifiedUserName;

// getters and setters
}
```

(Please excuse the formatting)

A stacktrace that was printed right before it gets stuck looks like this:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.leftOperand(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:52)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:72)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:72)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:72)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:72)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:72)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:72)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:72)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:72)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:72)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:72)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:72)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:72)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:72)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:72)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:72)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:72)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:72)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:208)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.accept(BinaryExpressionTreeImpl.java:72)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitVariable(BaseTreeVisitor.java:292)
    at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.VariableTreeImpl.accept(VariableTreeImpl.java:179)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBlock(BaseTreeVisitor.java:85)
    at org.sonar.java.model.statement.BlockTreeImpl.accept(BlockTreeImpl.java:77)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitTryStatement(BaseTreeVisitor.java:190)
    at org.sonar.java.model.statement.TryStatementTreeImpl.accept(TryStatementTreeImpl.java:172)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBlock(BaseTreeVisitor.java:85)
    at org.sonar.java.model.statement.BlockTreeImpl.accept(BlockTreeImpl.java:77)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitMethod(BaseTreeVisitor.java:80)
    at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.MethodTreeImpl.accept(MethodTreeImpl.java:215)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.helpers.ReassignmentFinder.getReassignments(ReassignmentFinder.java:84)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.helpers.ReassignmentFinder.getClosestReassignmentOrDeclarationExpression(ReassignmentFinder.java:58)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleVariableUsedAsQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:136)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:128)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleVariableUsedAsQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:138)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:128)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleVariableUsedAsQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:138)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:128)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleVariableUsedAsQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:138)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:128)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleVariableUsedAsQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:138)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:128)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleVariableUsedAsQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:138)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:128)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleVariableUsedAsQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:138)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:128)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleStringConcatenation(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:144)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.getNumberQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.handleVariableUsedAsQuery(PreparedStatementAndResultSetCheck.java:138)
```

Comment: You should be able to identify the file causing the issue and use it to create a reproducer that we can use to identify the problem.

Comment: Issue might not happen in a rule, so determining the file causing the issue is essential.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I've isolated some code that causes the problem.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using SonarQube 5.1.2 and had a pretty similar StackOverflowError in the class `PreparedStatement` And `ResultSetCheck`.

As a workaround I disabled the rule **S2695** until they get it working again.

Comment: This has been fixed in version 3.9 of the java plugin.
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1346

Answer (score -1):

We had the same StackOverflowError using SonarQube 4.5.6 and Java Plugin 3.7.
We disabled the rule S2695 as suggested.
We are waiting for the Java plugin 3.9 ( RD 23 Dec 2015 ).

Marry Chrustmas for all of us.

Comment: This answer should be a comment instead.